# Unable to run parallel tests in protractor

Tags: protractor, sharding

Unable to shard tests between browsers. Even though the config is set to shard them.

```
maxSessions: 2  ,
    capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            shardTestFiles: true,
            maxInstances: 2,
        },
```

It launches only one browser.

Answer (score 0):

That won't launch two browsers. You have to use `multicapabilities` like shown in the section *Testing again multiple browsers* of this [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md)

Answer (score 0):

use:
multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            shardTestFiles: true,
           maxInstances: 2,
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run test in multiple browsers(chrome, IE, firefox) then implement multi capabilities.

If you want to run test in single browser, but multiple instances then you used right config, just make sure you are passing more than 1 script or you can create different suites. For example:

```
suites:
{ 
    regressionTest: ['Scripts/*.js'],
    sampleTest :['Scripts/xxxx.js'] 
}
```